# Lobatto quadrature

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I have a question about Lobatto quadrature. Why the abscissas are the roots of the derivative of Legendre polynomial? Where should I get information about how to derive the abscissas and weights of Lobatto quadrature?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Lobatto quadrature we could derive similarly to the Gauss quadrature. We start with exactness (of the $n$-point Lobatto quadrature, $n\ge 2$) on polynomials of degree $\le 2n-3$. Then we can rather easily obtain the appropriate orthogonal polynomials. By examining (for instance) the recurrence for these polynomials we could arrive to the derivatives of Legendre polynomials.

The polynomials for the Lobatto quadratures are orthogonal with the weight function $1-x^2$.